# Force attribute exists in tags in XML

Tags: python, xml, lxml

How to remove all tags when parsing XML document if they don't have specific attribute? For example I want that all tags (except root of course) to have name attribute. I am using XML to have tree database and having tags without name simply doesn't have a sense.

Of course I just could iterate over all tags (deeply) and check if attribute exist but it will take some time with bigger files.

I guess there should be some option to do it with XMLParser... maybe using some schema?

Comment: [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) can probably do this very easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XPath and lxml, this should work:

```
from lxml import etree

xml = etree.XML("<root><a name='1'><b name='1-1'>ABC</b></a><a>Does not exist</a><a name='2'>DEF</a><a><b name='3-1'>GHI</b></a></root>")

print 'Before:'
print etree.tostring(xml)

xp = etree.XPath("/*/*[not(@name)]") # or "//*[not(@name)]" to include the root tag
all_nodes = xp(xml)
for x in all_nodes:
    parent = x.getparent()
    #if parent is None: continue # if the root tag is included, the parent is None
    parent.remove(x)

print 'After:'
print etree.tostring(xml)
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Now I am just using that right after parsing.

Comment: Glad it helps! Make sure you read more about XPath for more complex issues.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy in XSLT. Two template rules, an identity rule that copies everything:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and another rule that discards the elements you don't want:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(@specific-attribute)]"/>
```

Comment: Can you show how to use those with lxml? Also I don't quite get why I need both rules, why discarding rule isn't enough?

Comment: I don't know about XSLT but [this tutorial on lxml](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt) might help you. :)

Comment: I don't know anything about lxml, but this solution is completely generic and has minimal dependency on the actual vocabulary. The reason the first rule is needed is that the default built-in template rule in XSLT doesn't do what you want in this use case.